# Fetching data from MYSQL to a dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to fetch/retrieve data from my table and it will be placed in a drop-down list.Here's my code:

```
<?php
      $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select schedule from schedule"); 

      $result = mysqli_query($sql);
      echo "<select name='schedule'>";
      while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['schedule']. "'>" ."</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
?>
```

But an error says

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given 
>   Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in

Answer (score 0):

`$result = mysqli_query($sql);` should be removed, because you've already got the desired rows. 

In your while loop, change `$result` to `$sql` and everything should be fine.

Comment: thanks a lot its working,but the dropdown list is too small i couldn't see what words are written on it

Comment: That's because your `<option>` is empty. If you do something like this: `echo "<option value='" . $row['schedule']. "'>ITEM</option>";` it will show the text. I don't know what the values are of `schedule`, but you could do that instead of ITEM as well, of course.

Comment: got it working,I just placed the row between option open end close tag! thanks again

Comment: No problem! But if you want to use it later on, you need to make sure you give it a value as well so you can process it with PHP when you submit the form .